# Package dlib in AWS Lambda using Serverless and python 3.7

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-3.7, serverless-framework, dlib

I am trying to deploy an AWS Lambda function using Serverless framework with python3.7 runtime and I need to package dlib as a dependency and import inside the lambda function. Any ideas what's the easiest way to make dlib work on python3.7 and package successfully using the Serverless framework?
TIA...

**UPDATE:**
I already added dlib==19.9.0 to my requirements.txt, I am using the Serverless plugin serverless-python-requirements and I deploy using bitbucket pipeline based on an ubuntu image with python & node base.
I also install cmake in the pipeline script since dlib needs it to compile as I've seen.

The pipeline fails with:

```
Container 'Build' exceeded memory limit.
```

and the dlib compiling stops at 77% with the following recurring deprecation warnings until the pipeline exceeds memory and stops with failure:

```html
 Scanning dependencies of target dlib
.
.

 [ 77%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/other.cpp.o
    In file included from /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/cast.h:16,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/attr.h:13,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:43,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/dlib/../dlib/python/pybind_utils.h:6,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/dlib/../dlib/python.h:6,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/tools/python/src/basic.cpp:3:
    /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/internals.h:82:34: warning: ‘int PyThread_create_key()’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         decltype(PyThread_create_key()) tstate = 0; // Usually an int but a long on Cygwin64 with Python 3.x
                                      ^
    In file included from /usr/local/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:11,
                     from /usr/local/include/python3.7m/traceback.h:8,
                     from /usr/local/include/python3.7m/Python.h:119,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/common.h:111,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/pytypes.h:12,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/cast.h:13,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/attr.h:13,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:43,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/dlib/../dlib/python/pybind_utils.h:6,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/dlib/../dlib/python.h:6,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/tools/python/src/basic.cpp:3:
    /usr/local/include/python3.7m/pythread.h:95:17: note: declared here
     PyAPI_FUNC(int) PyThread_create_key(void) Py_DEPRECATED(3.7);
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In file included from /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/cast.h:16,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/attr.h:13,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:43,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/dlib/../dlib/python/pybind_utils.h:6,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/dlib/../dlib/python.h:6,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/tools/python/src/basic.cpp:3:
    /tmp/pip-install-nx1hok9_/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/internals.h:82:34: warning: ‘int PyThread_create_key()’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         decltype(PyThread_create_key()) tstate = 0; // Usually an int but a long on Cygwin64 with Python 3.x
                                      ^
    In file included from /usr/local/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:11,
```

Comment: Don't know about serverless framework, but I usually create lambda layers with my dependencies. For that i use the [lambci/lambda](https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/) docker tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I solved this by increasing the pipeline size to 2x and it succeeded

Answer (score 1):

Marcin's suggestion works but is somewhat tedious. Fortunately, here comes the serverless framework to the rescue. The following example uses Python 3.8, but can easily switch it to 3.7.

Prerequisites:

- You need [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/#download-and-install) if you are not natively running linux
- [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm)
- [Serverless Python Requirements](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements): `npm install --save serverless-python-requirements`

#### serverless.yml

```
service: dlib-example

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8

functions:
  dlib:
    handler: handler.main
    layers:
      - {Ref: PythonRequirementsLambdaLayer}

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
    layer: true
```

#### requirements.txt

```
dlib==19.19.0
```

#### handler.py

```
import dlib


def main(event, context):
    print(dlib.__version__)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('', '')
```

Then use `sls deploy` to build dependencies (in docker container) and deploy to AWS using CloudFormation.

#### Test

Run `sls invoke -f dlib --log` and you will get something like this:

```
null
--------------------------------------------------------------------
START RequestId: 9fba7253-2f3b-425f-a0b7-9ee3dfaec13b Version: $LATEST
19.19.0
END RequestId: 9fba7253-2f3b-425f-a0b7-9ee3dfaec13b
REPORT RequestId: 9fba7253-2f3b-425f-a0b7-9ee3dfaec13b  Duration: 1.66 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 62 MB  Init Duration: 227.31 ms
```

Cheers!

Comment: thanks for your answer.. this is exactly what I have in my serverless project, but my pipeline fails. I have updated my post with the errors I get, any ideas?

Comment: Try increasing the memory limit of the container. Those errors you posted seems like just some deprecation warnings.

Comment: well, I actually tried increasing the memory limit, but only get more of those deprecation warnings till the pipeline breaks. always freezes at just 77%

Comment: I increased the size to 2x and the installation finally completed. Thanks!

Comment: @RihamNour No problem. I'm glad it helps◡̈